# How can I hard code a json string into an *http.Response for testing purposes in Go

Tags: go

I have some code that makes get requests to a dynamic website, which I want to test. Obviously the tests need to be run by anyone at any time, so rather than actually use the REST API, is it possible to put a json string into an *http.Response for testing purposes.

example code:

```
func get (c *http.Response, err error) (string, error) {
    //code
}
```

test file:

```
func TestGet(t *testing.T) {
    //code to have put json string for test *http.Response
    get(???, nil)

}
```

Comment: Do you want somehow unmarshal a json string into an `http.Response` object? You can read a saved response via [http.ReadResponse](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ReadResponse)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use a `bytes.Buffer` to turn the data you have into an `io.Reader`, and `NopCloser` (from `io/ioutil`) to make it an `io.ReadCloser`

```
r := &http.Response{
    Status: "200 OK",
    StatusCode: 200,
    // etc., lots more fields needed here.
    Body: ioutil.NopCloser(bytes.NewBufferString(json))
}
```

If you have your json in a `[]byte`, then use `NewBuffer` instead of `NewBufferString`.

Comment: Is the json in this case a string, and if so, how do I hard code json as a string (since it will have multiple quotes in the json

Comment: @user6586806 your question implied you already had a JSON string. Anyway, you can use the raw string (`\`like this\``) quotes.